# want to do something when choose options from list (listpreference)

Tags: android, events, listpreference

I am using preference concept (listpreference) in my application.
I want to do something when i choose particular option from list
So plese tell me how is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

```
    startDatePref = findPreference("time");

...

    @Override
    public boolean onPreferenceTreeClick(PreferenceScreen preferenceScreen,
                                         Preference preference) {
        if (preference == startDatePref) {
            // your action
        }

        return super.onPreferenceTreeClick(preferenceScreen, preference);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [that post](http://www.kaloer.com/android-preferences) :

> To read these preferences from code,
>   we should create a getPrefs() method,
>   which we can call in the onStart()
>   method. When we call it in the
>   onStart() method instead of
>   onCreate(), we can be sure that the
>   preferences load when we have set them
>   and returned to our main activity,

```
private void getPrefs() {
                // Get the xml/preferences.xml preferences
                SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager
                                .getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());
                CheckboxPreference = prefs.getBoolean("checkboxPref", true);
                ListPreference = prefs.getString("listPref", "nr1");
                editTextPreference = prefs.getString("editTextPref",
                                "Nothing has been entered");
                ringtonePreference = prefs.getString("ringtonePref",
                                "DEFAULT_RINGTONE_URI");
                secondEditTextPreference = prefs.getString("SecondEditTextPref",
                                "Nothing has been entered");
                // Get the custom preference
                SharedPreferences mySharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(
                                "myCustomSharedPrefs", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
                customPref = mySharedPreferences.getString("myCusomPref", "");
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply!

Actually My problem is different.

My application has two tabs. In second tab preference screen appears out of which one is listpreference. When I choose any option from list for changing background screen then i did not get immediate effect in the preference screen with changed background image and when I go to first tab then i can look changed screen background and now when i come in second tab(preference screen)  then i got effect 
I want immediate response in preference screen with changed background image. Hope you will get what i need. pls suggest!

Answer (score 0):

make your preference activity implement onPreferenceChangeListener and then you need to find the preference by its key in onCreate and register the listener.